# Find array containing the most items from input array

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables as follows:

```
Table 1:
[1,2,3,4,5]

Table 2:
[2,3,4]
[1,4]
[9,5,7]
```

And my goal is to find the array from table 2 that contains the highest number of elements from table 1. In this example, the expected result would be record [2,3,4] from table 2.

So far I have the following, but I am struggling to get the max elements logic incorporated:

```
#standardSQL
WITH query_items AS (
  SELECT [96072688,25185958] AS items
),
lookup_values AS (
  SELECT antecedent from recommendation_engine.association_rules
)
SELECT query_items.items, lookup_values.antecedent
FROM query_items, lookup_values, UNNEST([(SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(query_items.items) - COUNT(1) 
                      FROM UNNEST(query_items.items) AS input 
                      JOIN UNNEST(lookup_values.antecedent)  AS output 
                      ON input = output)]) AS results
WHERE results = 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below example (for BigQuery Standard SQL) should give you an idea

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT [1,2,3,4,5] target
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT [2,3,4] candidates UNION ALL
  SELECT [1,4] UNION ALL
  SELECT [9,5,7] 
)
SELECT *, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM t1.target x 
    JOIN t2.candidates y 
    ON x=y
  ) matches
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
ORDER BY matches DESC
LIMIT 1
```

with result

```
#   target      candidates  matches
1   [1,2,3,4,5] [2,3,4]     3
```